# Excel - how to drag to fill: Increment only one value in a formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet, matching

How do I drag to fill the formula correctly?

`=MATCH(D6,M4:M373,0)`

I want to increment D6 ONLY, so that it looks like:

```
=MATCH(D7,M4:M373,0)
=MATCH(D8,M4:M373,0)
=MATCH(D9,M4:M373,0)
=MATCH(D10,M4:M373,0)
```

But dragging creates:

```
=MATCH(D7,M5:M374,0)
=MATCH(D8,M6:M375,0)
=MATCH(D9,M7:M376,0)'''

incrementing the match area - which I want to stay the same - M4:M373.

Thanks for your time all
```

Comment: `=MATCH(D6,M$4:M$373,0)`

Comment: A must [read](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-dfec08cd-ae65-4f56-839e-5f0d8d0baca9) for you.

Answer (score 2):

Use Absolute references `$`

```
=MATCH(D6,$M$4:$M$373,0)
```

Comment: Ya absolute or named range. Depending on how you look at it, neither absolute nor relative actually increment. Say cell B1 references A1. With relative it actually means one cell to the left. When dragging down to B2 it remains one cell to the left, which in this case is A2.

Answer (score 0):

put the `$` before the column letter and the row number to have them remain the same.
`=MATCH(D6,$M$4:$M$373,0)`

Comment: You have duplicated the other answer =)